# SFDX cli force:source vs force:mdapi?

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

I have been reading some mixed comments about the difference between **force:source** vs **force:mdapi**. So far my assumption is that **force:source** is used for scratch org and **force:mdapi** is used for sandbox/dev/prod org.

Q1) **force:source** vs **force:mdapi**

- What is the difference between **force:source** vs **force:mdapi**?

Q2) **force:source:*pull/push*** vs **force:source:*deploy/retrieve***

- I do not completely understand the difference between **force:source:pull/push** vs **force:source:deploy/retrieve**. I understand when a code change is done either locally or on scratch org pull/push can sync in both environments, but when will I need to use **force:source:deploy/retrieve**?

Q3) **force:*mdapi*:deploy/retrieve** vs **force:*source*:deploy/retrieve**

- What is the difference between **force:mdapi:deploy/retrieve** vs **force:source: deploy/retrieve** and when should they each be used?

*Goal:* My ultimate goal is to retrieve from production, do my development in scratch org, and deploy changes to development.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look through the [Salesforce DX Extensions User Guide](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/org-development-model)? While it's phrased mostly in terms of the UI commands, it explores all of the permutations. There are also excellent Trailhead modules on both Org and Package Development Models.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason they never mention **force:mdapi** in that page. I am trying to implement CI so therefore I need a clear understanding of the CLI

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What is the difference between force:source vs force:mdapi?

The file and directory structures are different. `force:source` refers to the new "source" format, while `force:mdapi` refers to the old "[metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/file_based_zip_file.htm)" format. As an example of the changes, in metadata format, a custom object is a single file, while in source format, an object has a core metadata file for the object itself, a folder full of files that represent each field, another folder for list views, etc.

> ... but when will I need to use force:source:deploy/retrieve?

For anything that is *not* a Scratch Org (including Production, Sandbox, and Developer Edition orgs). The difference here is that Scratch Orgs "track" changes, allowing developers to upload and download a delta (i.e. just the changes). Other orgs do not have this extra feature, and so you can only download and upload specified files, regardless if there has been any change. This means that it will typically take longer to upload and download changes, and it can be easier to miss changes.

> What is the difference between force:mdapi:deploy/retrieve vs force:source: deploy/retrieve and when should they each be used?

If you have metadata formatted files, use `force:mdapi`. If you have source formatted files, use `force:source`. If you have neither, use the source format, as it is easier to work with.

The mdapi commands are to allow migration from existing source code repos to the newer format over time. You should *prefer* to use the `force:source` commands whenever possible, and use the `force:mdapi` commands only when dealing with legacy code repositories that have not yet been converted to "source" format.

Migrating to source format also means you'll get the advantage of 2GP (Second generation packages), which allows you to create versions, dependencies, etc, so you can just install packages instead of uploading metadata every time. This greatly reduces deployment times and grants additional features, like the ability to delete an obsolete field by removing it from a package.

---

You can get your goals done with nothing other than force:source (and optionally force:package) command(s). You can use a Developer Edition org, or you might even decide to eventually migrate to Scratch Orgs.

Comment: Should probably mention that SFDX has a myriad of bugs and that nowhere close to everything can be deployed through packages.

Comment: @rzr Is this speaking from recent experience, or has it been a while? I remember trying to migrate to DX last year and I had a *ton* of problems, but as of Summer '19, I've been able to start migrating our org to scratch orgs and unlocked packages, and we have a *lot* of metadata. Unless you've got a super-complicated org, DX should be relatively painless.

Comment: I'm working with it right now on a fairly large project (although still a young one). My experience is that there's still a ton of issues with metadata support and change tracking in the CLI which makes us resort to MDAPI and ad-hoc powershell scripts to keep CI going and developers unblocked.